# Nginx Prometheus exporter fails to start with connection refused error

Tags: prometheus

I've setup Nginx Prometheus exporter from Nginx Inc. (https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter) on an Ubuntu 20.04 server.
Trying to start the service, an error shows up:

```
Could not create Nginx Client: failed to get https://domain.tld/nginx-status: Get "https://domain.tld/nginx-status": dial tcp 127.0.1.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

The url https://domain.tld/nginx-status is running fine.

This is the config file I'm using:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx Prometheus Exporter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=nginx_exporter
Group=nginx_exporter
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/nginx-prometheus-exporter \
    -web.listen-address=server_IP:9113 \
    -nginx.scrape-uri https://domain.tld/nginx-status

SyslogIdentifier=nginx_prometheus_exporter
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I see that `domain.tld` has been resolved to `127.0.1.1`. If both NGINX and the exporter are on the same machine, check if NGINX listens to this IP. If they're on different servers, check `/etc/hosts` where the exporter is for `domain.tld` entry.

Comment: What do you mean by "check if NGINX listens to this IP"? If Nginx listens on localhost as well?
Currently it listens on PUBLIC_IP:80, PUBLIC_IP:443, 0.0.0.0:8083 and 127.0.0.1:8084

Comment: There you have it. Your error message contains this: `dial tcp 127.0.1.1:443`. What than means, it that the exporter is not using public IP to connect to NGINX, it uses a loopback IP instead. You need to either change NGINX config so that it listen to any IP on port 443 or check `/etc/hosts` and remove domain.tld to 127.0.1.1 mapping.

Comment: And you can also add `listen 127.0.1.1:443;` to NGINX config if you like it that way.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was an entry in `/etc/hosts` file...

```
127.0.0.1 domain.tld
```

Now exporter is starting without any errors!

Thanks to @anemyte